# Converting NULLs to 0 in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The following code successfully generates a Pivot  (shown below the code)

```
select * 
from (
Select GLAccount , DC , Amount  from AccountingTxns a where Acctno = '178523'
)
TableData
pivot (
sum (Amount)
for DC in ([D],[C])
) 
as SumAmountDC
```

```
GLAccount             D       C
InterestDue     3801.37 3731.68
Cash            25600   25000
IntReceivable   3801.37 3801.37
IntIncome       NULL    3684.47
IntOverdue      NULL    116.9
Principal      25000    21868.32
```

How do i get rid of the NULLs (i.e. convert them to 0's)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `COALESCE`,

```
SELECT  GLAccount, 
        COALESCE(D, 0) D, 
        COALESCE(C, 0) C
FROM 
        (
            SELECT  GLAccount, 
                    DC , 
                    Amount  
            FROM    AccountingTxns a 
            WHERE   Acctno = '178523'
        ) TableData
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM(Amount)
            FOR DC IN ([D],[C])
        ) SumAmountDC
```

- [TSQL COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Tried different combinations. All gave errors. To clarify, the column name is DC and it has D or C as values. Some GLAccounts do not have either a D or a C and hence the Pivot gives NULL sums for those GLAccounts. Complete corrected code may help.

Comment: Thanks. Gave the right results. A small correction, however. The second last line should read "FOR DC IN.....". Please update.

Comment: When I ran the code using "SUM(AMOUNT) FROM DC IN ([D],[C])" it gave a syntax error . Replacing the "FROM" with "FOR" gave the correct results.

Comment: @user1955215 yep. sorry for that.